# Visual Studio 2013, 2015 Has stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem that when I try to open to create a new C# project in either VS 2013 or 2015, I get an error saying that the program has stopped working then it restarts. I tried disabling .Net Framework 3.5, but it didn't help, also I tried repairing it through the control panel, but it didn't help either. What shall I do?

---

> Uninstall and do a fresh reinstall? – Jacobr365

I DID uninstall Visual Studio 2013 before installing 2015.

> Clearing the component cache fixes some issues with Visual Studio: Delete C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio[Version]\ComponentModelCa‌​che or try starting in Safe Mode first: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /safemode – Mark

I tried both, but it didn't help.
Thanks

Comment: Uninstall and do a fresh reinstall?

Comment: Clearing the component cache fixes _some_ issues with Visual Studio: Delete `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[Version]\ComponentModelCache` or try starting in Safe Mode first: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /safemode`

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall both 2013/2015
With related packages (.net, sql...)
Then reinstall it

Warning: do this only if anything else doesn't worked

Comment: I really did uninstall VS 2013 and everything related to it then Installed 2015, but the problem didn't go away.

Comment: @SupahotFire I'm pretty sure that the problem is on uninstalling secondary packages

Comment: I think reinstalling Windows will fix the problem, but I don't want to do so.

Comment: if there's some kind of a software that would reset the registries and other Windows 10 files will fix it

Comment: @SupahotFire you can try CCleaner for fix register

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before, Use iobit uninstaller or as mention above Ccleaner to fully remove all secondary packages, If you use iobit then when you uninstall it will give you the option to completely clean it from the registry. Restart machine and install again, try install from the web installer. If problem persists then you will most likely have to reinstall your windows OS.

Comment: I really hate the long time Visual studio takes to be installed on my PC,but I found out that the error only happens when I open .CS files